# Concatenate two paths

Tags: bash, scripts

I want concatenate following:

```
current_dir=/home/akshay/UCS
source_dir=/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/
```

I want to produce something like this:

```
/home/akshay/UCS/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/
```

and then I will set above path as `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

How should I do this in **bash** script?

EDIT: the script so far:

```
current_dir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )" 
echo ${current_dir} 
# Extract parent directory. 
parent_dir="$( dirname ${current_dir} )" 
echo ${parent_dir} 
source_dir=/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/ 
echo "$parent_dir$source_dir"
```

only gives me `$parent_dir` back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply

```
current_dir=/home/akshay/UCS
source_dir=/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/
echo "$current_dir$source_dir"
```

And then export it

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$current_dir$source_dir
```

Comment: I am calculating current_dir in script. When I did above concatenation, it gives me only current_dir again.

Comment: Can you elaborate what's the "calculating" you're doing?

Comment: current_dir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
echo ${current_dir}
# Extract parent directory.
parent_dir="$( dirname ${current_dir} )"
echo ${parent_dir}
source_dir=/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/
echo "$parent_dir$source_dir"

Comment: You are not running this in one line right? the `#` will comment out the following command, try to separate it.

Comment: Please check edited post for actual script.

Comment: The script works for me.

Comment: Problem solved. I had created this file on Linux machine from eclipse on windows machine. I created same file in linux via command line and it worked. So it was the problem caused due to creating file on linux via eclipse on windows.  Thanks for your help guys!!